# d3js - .exit().remove() doesn't remove all data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I been trying to create a force layout. Everything works fine, except for one thing. The nodes that have been added, are not being removed even though the data is being removed

I am attaching only the code that corresponds to this problem since the whole code is too huge:

function start(initial) {

```
link = link.data(force.links(), function(d) { return d.source.id + "-" + d.target.id; });
link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link");
node = node.data(force.nodes());        
  nodes = node
    .enter()
    .append("div")
      .attr("class", function(d) {
        var className = "";
        if(d.className=="event-sub-label")
        className += "node color-class-" + (((colorScale(d.category)+1)%5)+1);
        else
        className += "node color-class-" + colorScale(d.category);
        if (d.className=="event-sub-label") { className += " pop-3"; //+ popScore(d.activity_score) 
        }
        else { className += " " + d.className; }
        if (!initial) { className += " new-node new-indicator"; }
        return className;
      })
      .attr("id", function(d) { return d.id; });

 if (initial) {
    nodes = nodes
      .style("transform", "scale(0)")
      .style("-webkit-transform", "scale(0)")
  } else {
    nodes = nodes
      .style("transform", "scale(.01)")
      .style("-webkit-transform", "scale(.01)")
  }

  var events = {};
  var cancelEvent = function (d) {
    if (!events[d.id])
      return;

    clearTimeout(events[d.id]);
    return true;
  };
  nodes = nodes
    .on("mouseover", function (d) {
      var self = this;
      cancelEvent(d);
      events[d.id] = setTimeout(function () { events[d.id] = null; mouseoverNode.call(self, d); }, 100);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function (d) {
      if (cancelEvent(d) || d.dragging)
        return;

      mouseoutNode.call(this, d);
    })
    .call(nodeDrag);

  nodes.filter(function(d) { return d.image_url; })
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "article-image")
    .attr("style", function (d) {
      return "background-image: url(" + d.image_url + ")";
    })

  var ellipses = nodes.append("div").attr("class", "ellipse");

  ellipses.append("h2")
    .html(function(d) {
        return d.title_truncated;     
    })
    .attr("class", "title-preview");

    node.exit().remove();   //The old nodes should be removed here
    link.exit().remove();
```

updateNode(){  // To add new nodes

```
$.each(eventDict, function (c) {
        if(catEventFlag[eventDict[c].node.category].flag==2)
            collapse(this,eventDict[c].node);
    });

    function addNodes(category)
    {
        _.each(subEvents[category], function (c) {
            dataset.push(c.node);
        });    
        $.each(dataset, function (i, c) {
            if(c.className== "event-sub-label")
                processInternalNode(c);
        });

        d.thisClicked = true;
        d.fixed = true;
        runUpdate = false;

        start(true);        
        force
            .charge(chargeAlt)
            .alpha(.01)
            .start();
    }

    var category=d.category;
    d.thisClicked = true;

    if(catEventFlag[category].flag==0)
    {
        catEventFlag[category].flag=2;
        var fileName = category +'.json';
        d3.json(fileName, function(blah) {
            root = blah;

            $.each(root, function (i, dd) {
            var c=dd.event;
            subEvents[category][i] = {
                node: {
                    //Node Data
                    },
                x: xCoords[i],
                y: yCoords[i]
                };
            });
            addNodes(category);
        });
    }
    else if(catEventFlag[category].flag==1)
        addNodes(category);
```

and
Collapse(){ //For collapsing Node

```
var category = d.category;
catEventFlag[category].flag=1;
d.thisClicked = false;
console.log(links);

    function executeSplicing(){

    var i = links.length-1;
    while (i >=0 ) {
    console.log(i+" "+links[i].source.id);
    if (links[i].source.className == "event-sub-label")
    {
        //console.log("link?");
        links.splice(i,i+1);
    }
    i--;
    }
    nodes[0].splice(node[0].length-5); //Nodes and links Spliced already
    console.log(force.nodes());       //force.nodes() still has the old data
    return true;
    }

    start(executeSplicing());

 force.stop()
    .charge(charge)
    .alpha(.05)
    .start();
```

}

Please let me know if the code is too confusing. I will try and remove further parts from it to make it even more simple. The issue at hand is "updateNodes" function adds the nodes properly, and the force layout also gets the new nodes. But in the collapse function, the nodes are spliced from "nodes" var, but the data is not removed from force.nodes();

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are reassigning `nodes` several times throughout your code. After that, there's no exit selection anymore. Operate on the exit selection before reassigning.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks for the help. I couldn't understand how the .exit().remove() worked earlier. But thanks to your comment, I could understand about it and hence was able to fix it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure that someone else facing a similar problem, gets the answer outright!

Here, in the code, the data that is connected to the nodes is in the var "dataset". So, on updating the data in "dataset" alone will make .exit().remove() work as Lars Kotthoff as suggested. Updating the "nodes" alone won't suffice as I've done in the question. Hope this helps the other D3.JS beginners around.